# How to extract columns based on max of another colums

Tags: r

I have a dataset and I am looking to extract the state name having the highest female.
let's say the data can look like.
Ps: keep it simple,

I have tried

```
df$State.name[max(female)]

df$State.name[max(df$female)]

with(df, State.name[max(female)
```

but nothing worked

See the attached image

[image]

Comment: Try `df$State.name[which.max(df$female)]`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. however, can you let me know why my code did not show up